# How to list threads were killed by the kernel?

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

Is there any way to list all the killed processes in a linux device?

I saw this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/where-can-i-see-a-list-of-kernel-killed-processes) suggesting:

check in:

```
/var/log/kern.log
```

but it is not generic. there is any other way to do it?

### **What I want to do:**

list thread/process if it got killed. What function in the kernel should I edit to list all the killed tid/pid and their names, or alternitavily is there a `sysfs` does it anyway?

Comment: Are you actually referring to OOM(Out of Memory)-killer, or some other form of "killed process" (which is different from "killed threads" that your subject says - it would help to know which you are asking about, as I'm not 100% sure the answer is the same for both).

Comment: I edited the question, I want to list threads & processes before they get killed or to see all the killed ones

Comment: So, everytime someone does `ls | more` and then preccess `q` to quit out of the long listing, you want to see that `ls` died from `EPIPE`? And every time someone preccess CTRL-C to stop something? 

Or just those that are killed by some other reason? 

Why do you want this? {Your original link does talk about some "acct" software that appear to do something like that}

Comment: @MatsPetersson I want to do it the simplest way. what function in kernel is the opposite of do_fork?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that - I'm not asking HOW you want to do this, but WHY you want to do it. Is it for every single process in the system, or only some?

Comment: I want to log all the deleted task on my machine, for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of `do_fork` is `do_exit`, here:
[do_exit kernel source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/exit.c#L810)

I'm not able to find when threads are exiting, other than:

[release_task](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/exit.c#L180)

I believe "task" and "thread" are (almost) synonymous in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

First, task and thread *contexts* are different in the kernel.
task (using tasklet api) runs in software interrupt context (meaning you cannot sleep while you are in the task ctx) while thread (using kthread api, or workqueue api) runs the handler in process ctx (i.e. sleep-able ctx).

In both cases, if a thread hangs in the kerenl, you cannot kill it.
if you run "ps" command from the shell, you can see it there (normally with "[" and "]" braces) but any attempt to kill it won't work.

the kernel is trusted code, such a situation shouldn't happen, and if it does, it indicates a kernel (or kernel module) bug.

normally the whole machine will hand after a while because the core running that thread is not responding (you will see a message in /var/log/messages or the console with more info) in some other cases the machine may survive but that specific core is dead. depends on the kernel configuration.